# Add new items to enumeration of an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, list, anonymous-types

I must add new items to anonymous type. I have tried a lot of solutions, but it doesn't work. 
Here is the my code

Code:

```
var literByBeerBrand = (from salesResult in clientSalesResult.Liste.OrderBy(a => a.SaleDay)
                      select new
                      {
                          date = salesResult.SaleDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                          value = salesResult.TotalCl / 5642
                      }).ToList()
                      .GroupBy(k => k.date)
                      .Select(y => new {value = y.Sum(x=>x.value), date = y.First().date});

for (int i = 0; i <= diff.Days; i++)
{
    if (!(literByBeerBrand
        .Any(y => y.date == firstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))))
    {
        var t = new
        {
            value = 0,
            date = firstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

        };
        // HERE I MUST ADD NEW ITEM TO ANONYMOUS TYPE
    }

    firstDate = firstDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

I have tried before

```
1) literByBeerBrand.ToList()[literByBeerBrand.ToList().Count()] = t;

2) literByBeerBrand.ToList().Add(new
                {
                    value = 0,
                    date = firstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                });
```

Comment: Your "anonymous" type seems to be a `KeyValuePair` actually. Can you post where you declare `literByBeerBrand` in the first place please?

Comment: what is `literByBeerBrand`?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a compilation error? What is the element type of `literByBeerBrand`? At the moment you are trying to create a new list and add an item to that, rather than `literByBeerBrand`.

Comment: By 'anonymous type' do you mean 'a collection of instances of anonymous type'?

Comment: Missing context.  Always post a minimal but ***complete*** program. Otherwise, we have to guess the missing parts.

Comment: why -7 score really??

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve? It looks like you're trying to add a new entry into 'literByBeerBrand' for every day between a given date range. Why are you trying to create effectively blank entries?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a collection of objects of anonymous type without using `var`, so there is no easy way of adding items from scratch.

However, you can rewrite your code as LINQ, and use `ToList() / ToArray()` on it:

```
var res = Enumerable
    .Range(0, diff.Days+1)
    .Where(addedDays => literByBeerBrand.All(y => y.date != firstDate.AddDays(addedDays).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")))
    .Select(addedDays => new {
        value = 0,
        date = firstDate.AddDays(addedDays).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are for temporary use. What you want is a list of a class.

```
public class BeerType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

List<BeerType> literByBeerBrand = new List<BeerType>();
```

Now you can add items to `literByBeerBrand` all day long:

```
literByBeerBrand.Add(new BeerType { Value = 0, Date = firstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") };
```

It's natural for you to be extremely secretive about the declaration of `literByBeerBrand`; how can people possibly help you use it better if they know what its actual type is? That would be crazy talk. But since you keep converting it to a list, I'm going to guess that it's some kind of `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is an anonymous type.

What this line does, is it creates *a new temporary `List<T>` object*, adds an item to it, and then *throws that object away*.

```
literByBeerBrand.ToList().Add(new
            {
                value = 0,
                date = firstDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

            });
```

That doesn't get you anywhere.